# How to find the variable value in an XML array in powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a simple XML

```
<bds>
    <bd>
        <id>10</id>
        <user>john</user>
        <servers>
            <name>pc24</name> 
        </servers>
    </bd>
    <bd>
        <id>12</id>
        <user>peter</user>
        <servers>
            <name>pc25</name> 
        </servers>
    </bd>
</bds>
```

I have the attribute variable and its value is pc25.

```
$attribute = "pc25"
```

I can create an array with all nodes name and store their value but, how can I loop through that array looking for a match with the bariable?

```
$array = @($xml.SelectNodes("//name"))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use foreach like below

```
[xml]$xml ='<bds>
    <bd>
        <id>10</id>
        <user>john</user>
        <servers>
            <name>pc24</name> 
        </servers>
    </bd>
    <bd>
        <id>12</id>
        <user>peter</user>
        <servers>
            <name>pc25</name> 
        </servers>
    </bd>
</bds>'

foreach ($var in $xml.bds.bd) {
    $var
}
```

To get name attribute value of name

```
foreach ($var in $xml.bds.bd) {
    $var.servers.name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using an XPath query via the [`System.Xml.XmlDocument.SelectNodes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlNode.SelectNodes) method anyway, you can integrate the name filtering into that query (note that I'm using `$value` instead of `$attribute` as the variable name to avoid confusion):

```
$array = @($xml.SelectNodes("//name[. = '$value']/../.."))
```

Note that the above returns the enclosing `<bd>` elements that have the search term in their `servers/name` subpath. If you really only want the `<name>` elements, omit the `/../..` part.

---

A **more robust** way of formulating the above, matching the `bd` elements directly, via the content of the relevant descendant elements, identified by their relative paths:

```
$array = @($xml.SelectNodes("/bds/bd[servers/name = '$value']"))
```